# View won't render any content/teaser, only shows fields

Tags: views

I'm having a couple of articles which I want to display in a view. So I've set up a new view and made the following setting there:

```
Format: Unordered List | [default settings]
Show: Content | Full Content
```

All other settings remain untouched as default.

In the views-preview it is displayed nicely, but the whole view doesn't show up on the page when browsing to the path.

I've also tried

```
Show: Content | Teaser
Show: Rendered entity | Full Content
```

with no luck.

Only if I set the view to

```
Show: Fields
```

the view is displayed.

The article node pages are being displayed without a problem.
I'm working with views for years now, and never had such a problem.
Any ideas where the problem is?

Thanks, Marc

Comment: Can you check if you have any custom views template which is causing this issue?

Comment: Bharat: I'm not using any views template overrides.

Comment: Do you have any template for full content  view mode? Can you try to change the view mode from full content to teaser or something else?

Comment: Do you mean in the node's display settings? Yes, there is a display for full and teaser, each has fields to display.

Answer (score 0):

check if this view did not get somehow to disabled list... go views list it's divided into Enabled and Disabled lists check there...

Comment: Forey Vitaliy: Its active. It even shows the views title, but no content on the page.